# using one function for frontend and backend

Tags: php, codeigniter

I put my problem, I created a table "comments" then I maked a controller which two functions are implemented,  function for reading and the one other for insertion.

What I need now is to realize function for managing comments, ie beside  each comments there is an options delete and modify.

So,I add a new function that I named manage (), then, to avoid some repetition I think keep read (used to list the comments) and using it into manage() then add these stufs(modify,delete) beside each comment.
But I don't know how to proceed?
I need your advice help!

```
 <?php
 class Site extends CI_Controller {
     public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //  Chargement des ressources pour tout le contrôleur
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('comments_model', 'livreorManager');
    }
    function index() {
        $this->read();
       // $this->add();
    }
    function read() {

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->load->library('mytable');


        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/index.php/site/index';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('comments')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config['num_links'] = 20;

        $tmpl = array ( 'table_open'  => '<table class="table table-striped">' );
        $this->table->set_template($tmpl);



        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
         $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
        $data['records'] = $this->db->get('comments',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

        $data['donnees'] = $data['records']->result_array();
        $this->load->view('site_view', $data);

    }
    function add() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
         $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="form_erreur">', '</p>');

         $this->form_validation->set_rules('pseudo',  '"Pseudo"',  'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[25]|alpha_dash');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', '"Comment"', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[3000]');

        if($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $this->livreorManager->add_comment($this->input->post('pseudo'),$this->input->post('comment'));
            $this->load->view('success');
            $this->read();

        }

        else {
            $this->load->view('add');
        }
    }
    function manage() {
        // implément options into read
        $this->read();

    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't exactly get your problem. Can you explain what is that you want to do?

Comment: it's easy, I have my function read() (generate list of comments as table), I wanna use this function read() into manage() and then  add options delete and modify beside each comment (include delete and modify to read() )  (my goal is to avoid repition of read() ) if you still do not understand my problem, please tell me, I explain more

Comment: You can pass a parameter something like function read($manage = false) and then in the manage section you can pass $manage as true and generate the links which is required for managing the comments.. does that answer your question?

Comment: effectively, but is it recommanded? and secure?

Comment: Yes, I don't see any issue with this. You should assign a default value though. This way it will make sure anywhere else if the function is used, then it will continue to work without the error of missing parameter error and also you are handling a default value and checking for it.